# using migration with entity framework code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, database-migration

I'm using entity framework 4.1 in Asp.net MVC3 project, it's been deployed and now working, so now I'm gonna to update it, add some Non nullable fields and remove some fields from data base,absolutely I need my exiting data,so what's the best way to do this? is there any good tools to do that??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could consider code first and [Entity Framework Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).